# Sigma field and probability of evemts

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Let $\mathcal B$ denote a sigma field associated with a sample space $\omega$. Suppose $A$ and $B$ are members of $\mathcal B$. Let $P$ be a probability function defined on $\mathcal B$. Show that $$ P(A) + P(B) \le 2 (P(A)P(B))^\frac 12 $$

I am stuck on how to prove this. I tried using the Bonferroni's Inequality. But that didnt help me much. How do i approach this?

Comment: First of all, I assume you don't want to use $B$ for an event and the sigma field. Second of all, this is clearly false as stated.

Comment: The assertion is false. Suppose that we flip an unfair coin, where $A$ and $B$ denote heads and tails, respectively, with $P(A) = 1/4$ and $P(B) = 3/4$. Then the LHS of the inequality is $1$, but the RHS is $2\sqrt{3/16} < 1$. In fact, the opposite inequality holds, as can be deduced by squaring both sides of the one presented.

Comment: @T.Bongers, I just made the necessary corrections. The right symbol is used.

Comment: This is obviously false.  Just let $A$ be any event with positive probability and let $B$ be an event with probability $0$.  Hint:  look at the comment from @Bungo

Answer (score 1):

Assertion cannot be true for arbitrary $A,B$.

$P(A) + P(B) \leq 2(P(A)P(B))^{1/2} \iff (P(A) + P(B))^2 \leq 4P(A)P(B) \iff P(A)^2 -2P(A)P(B) + P(B)^2 = (P(A) -P(B))^2 \leq 0 \iff P(A) = P(B)$

Hence, it is true iff $P(A) = P(B)$, in which case the condition is reduced to a trivial statement.